# Force Javascript keydown on autocomplete input Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have the following problem I need that when I click "Enter" on an input with auto complete of Google Maps, then it press the down key to select a Google Maps option .. tried in several ways more did not work! I have the following code:

```
jQuery('.find-by__autocomplete').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.which = 40;
        jQuery(".find-by__autocomplete").trigger(e);
    }
});
```

Thanks!